# Transparent fixed header with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fixed

I've been trying to make a page with a fixed transparent header, using flexbox. At first, I found that somehow this causes a confliction (the fixed positioning and the flex) and the justify-content or align-items properties won't work on the child elements of the wrapper flex-fixed parent. The child elements of the fixed parent won't space appropriately.

But then I saw this https://templated.co/industrious, and somehow it works!
So I cannot understand why it doesn't work with my code. It seems to me I'm not doing it differently.

The header-fixed-flex div wraps the LOGO, NAV and search (svg) elements, but I cannot make the justify-content or align-items option to work on header-nav and navigation div's.

```css
    body {
        height: 2500px;
    }
    
    .header-fixed-flex {
        max-width: 150rem;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        transform: translate(19.2rem, 0);
    }
    
    .header_nav {
        max-width: 155rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .header_logo {
        max-height: 9.7rem;
        background: rgba(3, 12, 77, 0.4);
    }
    
    .header_link {
        padding: 0.5rem;
    }
    
    .navigation {
        background: rgba(191, 218, 218, 0.4);
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .navigation_list {
        list-style: none;
        letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .navigation_item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }
    
    .navigation_link:link, .navigation_link:visited {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0.8rem;
    }
    
    .navigation_button {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .navigation_search-input {
        border: none;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        outline: none;
        width: 5rem;
    }
    
    .navigation_icon {
        padding: 0.5rem;
        width: 3rem;
        fill: #fff;
    }
    
    .hero_img {
        background: url(https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1350072692/t1/img/front_page/jp-mountain@2x.jpg) top/cover;
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header-fixed-flex">
        
        <div class="header_nav">
            <header class="header_logo">
                <a href="index.html" class="header_link">LOGO</a>
            </header>
          
            <nav class="navigation">
                <ul class="navigation_list">
                    <li class="navigation_item">
                        <a href="#" class="navigation_link">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation_item">
                        <a href="#" class="navigation_link">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation_item">
                        <a href="#" class="navigation_link">Articles</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation_item">
                        <a href="#" class="navigation_link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="navigation_button">
                    <input type="text" class="navigation_search-input" id="search-query"/>
                    <label for="search-query" class="navigation_search_label"></label>
                    <svg class="navigation_icon"></svg>
                </button>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="hero_img"></div>
    </section>
```

Or a codepen link with scss 
https://codepen.io/tantoniou/pen/QoGmba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really tough to determine what you want from your writeup with no design comp or wireframe provided, but my initial guess is things aren't happening as you expect because `.header-fixed-flex` only has one child. So maybe setting `flex: 1` or just `width: 100%` on `.header_nav` will get things working as you like.

Comment: Actually you just answered my question! It was right in front of me!
I considered that the fixed-flex parent wrapped two child elements (header and nav), but it is the header_nav that has these as childs, and therefore works if it is the first flex parent!
Thank you very much!

Comment: (I removed part of the design to make this more simple, and because I cannot reference my own images, logos etc, but I thought the code snippet and/or the codepen will work, sorry for that!)

Comment: Glad to help. You'll probably want to mark the answer as the solution. It helps other people to know that you don't need help anymore, and I get delicious Fake Internet Points.

Comment: This was my first question here. It means a lot finding help when in frustration! I'll make sure to contribute anyway I can here!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the header-fixed-flex element and apply this style on header_nav

```
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```